# PROJ pyproj conversion of point EPSG 4326 (WSG 84) to (EPSG 28992)

Tags: python, gis, coordinate-systems, pyproj

Given a (lon, lat) point (5.068913, 52.067567) I would like to convert from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 28992 using `pyproj`.

The `Proj`, and `transform` functions in `pyproj` both seem to be suitable for such a task:

- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/proj.html?highlight=proj#pyproj-proj
- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/transformer.html?highlight=transform#pyproj-transform

When I use the `Proj` function I get a different result to using `transform`, why?

For example

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pyproj import Proj, transform

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = 5.068913, 52.067567

in_proj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') 
out_proj = Proj(init='epsg:28992')

point1 = Point(out_proj(x1, y1))
point2 = Point(transform(in_proj, out_proj, x1 ,y1))

print(point1 == point2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = point1.xy
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
x, y = point2.xy
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

[image: points]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion between

> EPSG:4326

and

> EPSG:28992

requires not only projecting the input coordinates, using the Oblique_Stereographic projection, in this case. That can be accomplished with the `Proj` function...

...but also performing a datum transformation, WGS84 to Amersfoort datum. That can only be accomplished with the `transform` function. Note that `transform` does everything that `Proj` does plus datum transformations. There is no need for a two-step transformation.

Illustrating what have been said, we have for `EPSG:28992` the following [WKT](https://epsg.io/28992),

```
PROJCS["Amersfoort / RD New",
    GEOGCS["Amersfoort",
        DATUM["Amersfoort",
            SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
            TOWGS84[565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6289"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4289"]],
    PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52.15616055555555],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",5.38763888888889],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999079],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",155000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",463000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","28992"]]
```

The string

> TOWGS84[565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725]

...implies the need to perform a datum conversion... that cannot be acomplished with the `Proj`function, but only with `transform`.

Conclusion:

Assuming the `pyproj` installation you are using is configured with the correct `TOWGS84` strings (that is not always the case), then the `transform` result should be the one to be considered correct.

Comment: How can I check that the pyproj installation I am using is configured with the correct TOWGS84 strings?

Comment: You'll have to check inside the `/usr/share/proj/epsg/` file for the corresponding `+towgs84` string.